# Can File.WriteAllBytes() could fail without throwing an exception?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

We are using `System.File.WriteAllBytes()` method to store documents in one of our solutions.

In the production environment this method has wrote **some** files in disk with **0 bytes**. But we are logging the size of the files that we are writing right before writing them to the disk and they are more than 0 bytes. And this has happend only to some files.

We have lost some data because of this.

Could it be a possibility for `File.WriteAllBytes()` to fail after writing a 0 bytes file without throwing an exception?

Can anyone explain the cause of this?

Comment: We'd be better able to explain with a code example, to be honest. It should give an exception.

Comment: I think you have a bug in your application. Where the bytes come from? How you measure before write?

Comment: Please share the code that is doing the writing and/or estimating byte count so that we can assist

Comment: Check the EventViewer if there was some disk error at that time.

Comment: I think that you need to check the array byte you're writing before calling the method.
If you want an alternative solution, try to use StreamWriter, and check if you still have the same problem

Comment: @ThomasWeller that would just work ;-) It's not the desired result. But it should just work and not throw an exception. So the answer to his question is: it should **always** throw an exception if it fails. The byte array probably fails in a try catch or something causing it to stay empty and it's just written as an empty array to a file.

Comment: Catastrophic failures (power outage) may leave the file in an older state than what the OS promised, but hopefully you'd be seeing other signs of such failures also)

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Soft disk failures are possible... Windows won't blue-screen if a disk fails a writing... And if that writing was on the file allocation table, the size will remain 0.

Answer (score 1):

The method should throw an exception in case of failures.

However, consider the following case

```
File.WriteAllText(@"d:\temp\test.txt", "Content");
File.WriteAllBytes(@"d:\temp\test.txt", new byte[0]);
```

In above scenario, the second statement writes 0 bytes into the file and trucates *) the file, so that there will be a 0 byte file on disk. Note that this is not a problem, but the expected behavior, so make sure that the `byte[]`you use for writing is not empty.

*) aka "overwritten" according to [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.io.file.writeallbytes(v=vs.110).aspx), which does not mean overwriting the first *n* bytes but overwriting the whole file

Other options may be hardware failures. Above statement results in 3 disk operations, which can be monitored with [ProcessMonitor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon):

1. [CreateFile](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-createfilew): creates a 0 byte file, thus deleting the existing file
2. [WriteFile](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-writefile): Writes the contents to disk
3. [CloseFile](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/windows/desktop/ms724211(v=vs.85).aspx)

If there's a power outage after step 1 but before step 2, the file may be empty. From .NET point of view, the operation may have succeeded, but from OS point of view the file content were in the write cache only.